# Code generating props when newing object

Tags: c#, resharper

I have an object with 100 properties. Is there a feature in Resharper or Visual Studio 2017 that generates the code for all the properties of the object. e.g.

```
var myObject = new ObjectWithMultipleProps
{
   Prop1 = "",
   Prop2 = 0,
   Prop3 = "",
   ...etch
}
```

I am creating unit tests and it would speed up things if this would be possible.

Comment: Why should the generator make a string default to the empty string instead of `null`? You need some logic for those defaults of course, which no software can guess. Apart from this problem you didn´t seem to have anything done so far, do you?

Comment: null is ok as well, just want to set all the props...

Comment: If `null` is okay, that´s exactly what happens anyway when creating the instance. It is filled with the default-values for every type, `null` for reference-types, zero for `int`, `float` and all other numeric types. There´s no need to *re-set* the defaults.

Comment: Yes, that's correct but at least the properties would be written out and I wouldn't have to set them manually :s I want to be able to speed up the process of editing the values I need. But if this is not possible I guess I will have to do it manually :)

Comment: Anyway, having a single object with so many properties seems odd to me and is a sign of a code-smell.

Comment: I recomment using NimbleText

Comment: @HimBromBeere yes I agree, it's an old system that I need to unit test :s

Comment: At least Resharper shows only the props that haven´t already been used :)

Comment: "I wouldn't have to set them manually" You don´t have to. All numbers are implictely set to zero anyway. You can use `myObject = new ObjectWithMultipleProps()` and then `Console.WriteLine(myObject.Prop)`. At least the compiler is fine with that, as it intializes `Prop1` to `null`.

Comment: Yes, thing is I need to check which one are mandatory

Comment: That´s a completely different thing. However what *is* mandatory?

Comment: Required attributes...

Comment: The question is: what do you consider to be required and what is optional? In your example: what is what?

Comment: My question is what it states, is it possible to code generate properties when newing an object.

Comment: You could write that code in the constructor of `ObjectWithMultipleProps`. However this is obsolete, as the runtime will infer the exact same values for you anyway. There´s no chance for your object to have the properties *not* set to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

type this much:

```
var myObject = new ObjectWithMultipleProps {
```

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>.  The next unused field or Property will get auto completed for you.  You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> again and it will pop up the type of the field so you can choose an appropriate value.  Or you can start typing `new` then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and it will auto-complete the type for you.

Then type a comma, and repeat the process for each field.  Fields that you have already specified will not appear in the list.  If you do not want to set a value for a field, then omit it from the initializer list, and it will get its default value.

Comment: Hi @Wyck thanks for the suggestion. I am using the Visual Studio keyboard scheme for Resharper. When I press ctrl + j I get the a general context menu. However if I press ctrl + space I get the attributes context menu. I still have to manually set the properties. It helps that fields I have already specified are not appearing in the list.

Comment: From what I understood, you wanted to manually set the properties, you just wanted the list of properties to be auto-populated for you.  Did I misunderstand?

Comment: Yes, you are right it would be great if there was a feature to auto populate all the properties of an object with their default values written out.

Comment: ...so that you can just edit them again?  You're looking for placeholders that you intend to replace?  I can confirm that feature doesn't exist in Visual Studio.  I would also argue that the whole point of object oriented programming is **not** to write that kind of code, so that's probably why it doesn't exist, although I can see why you want it for unit tests.  You'd have to write it as an extension.  I suppose you could make a feature request for "explicitly initialize all fields and properties" to the Resharper team.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a misunderstanding on what *creating an instance* means. There´s no way for an instantiated object (this is when you called `new ...`) to have no value for any of your members. All those members are initialized from the runtime to the default-type for the type of that member. In particular you can´t *partly initialize* your object, that is set only some members to an initial-value, whilst not setting others. Creating an instance is an all-or-nothing-operation.

So if you simply write this:

```
var myObject = new ObjectWithMultipleProps();
```

all properties within `myObject` *will* have their defualt-value. You can even print them:

```
Console.WriteLine(myObject.Prop2);  // this will print 0
```

You coul of course write all those assignments into the class´ constructor:

```
class ObjectWithMultipleProps
{
    public ObjectWithMultipleProps()
    {
        Prop1 = null;
        Prop2 = 0;
    }
}
```

This however has the exact same effect.

What may happen anyway is, that you get a `NullReferenceException`. This is because all reference-types default to `null`, making any call to those members yield to that exception, as shown in the following code:

```
var a = myObject.Prop1.SubsString(0, 1);
```

As `Prop1` is initialized to `null` once the instance is completely created, you get a `NullReferenceException`, because you can´t call any member on `null`.

If you want other default-values for your members, you have to create the constructor and set the values there.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the clarification. Instead of writing the assignments manually I was hoping Resharper could help me out :) by generating it manually with a default value. It has many nice code generation features so I assumed this would be possible.